# Javascript: slideshow not slide when click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have simple code where is slideshow which automatic slides every 5000ms.

Now I tried to make button which when I click on this button next image will not slide every 5000ms but when I click.

When I make code like this browser giving me errors.

Is there any solutions or I need make ned slideshow?

**This is original code:**

```
function cycleBackgrounds() {
var index = 0;

$imageEls = $('.container .slide');

setInterval(function () {
    index = index + 1 < $imageEls.length ? index + 1 : 0;
    $imageEls.eq(index).addClass('show');
    $imageEls.eq(index - 1).removeClass('show');

}, 5000);
};

$(function () {
    cycleBackgrounds();
});
```

**This is added code:**

```
function rightSlide() {
    index = index + 1 < $imageEls.length ? index + 1 : 0;
    $imageEls.eq(index).addClass('show');
    $imageEls.eq(index - 1).removeClass('show');
  }
```

**EDIT added HTML**

```
<section class="slide show" style="background-image: url('https://s7img.ftdi.com/is/image/ProvideCommerce/FTD_19_EDAY_19M3_HP_HEROBANNER?$ftd-product-banner-lv$');">
    <div class="slide-content-wrapper">
        <div class="slide-content">
            <h2>02</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
<section class="slide" style="background-image: url('https://s7img.ftdi.com/is/image/ProvideCommerce/FTD_19_EDAY_19M3_HP_HEROBANNER?$ftd-product-banner-lv$');">
    <div class="slide-content-wrapper right">
        <div class="slide-content">
            <h2>01</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: could you please add the Html

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are creating an interval and then never clearing it. This means that once the interval is created it will keep going on forever (currently). You can read more about intervals [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp).

To briefly explain how to solve it:

1. You need to assign the interval to a variable
2. When you want to manually change images then clear the interval

Code snippet from the site:

```
var myVar = setInterval(myTimer, 1000);

function myTimer() {
  var d = new Date();
  var t = d.toLocaleTimeString();
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = t;
}

function myStopFunction() {
  clearInterval(myVar);
}
```

Inside of your code, when creating the interval you need to assign it into a variable and inside of the function `rightSlide()` you would need to clear it `clearInterval(<yourIntervalHere>);`

```
var intervalVariable = setInterval(function () {
    index = index + 1 < $imageEls.length ? index + 1 : 0;
    $imageEls.eq(index).addClass('show');
    $imageEls.eq(index - 1).removeClass('show');
}, 5000);

function rightSlide() {
    clearInterval(intervalVariable);
    index = index + 1 < $imageEls.length ? index + 1 : 0;
    $imageEls.eq(index).addClass('show');
    $imageEls.eq(index - 1).removeClass('show');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to clear the interval but that's not the only problem:

Probably, the `$imageEls` and `index` variables are not in the scope of your custom click handler. It is definitely not the cleanest solution, but for now we will add them to the global `window` object

This is how I would write it (untested):

```
function cycleBackgrounds() {
    window.index = (window.index + 1 < window.$imageEls.length) ? window.index + 1 : 0;
    window.$imageEls.eq(index).addClass('show');
    window.$imageEls.eq(index - 1).removeClass('show');

}

$(function () {
    // add the new variables to window so they are globally accessible
    window.index = 0;
    window.$imageEls = $('.container .slide');
    // start sliding images
    window.slideshow_interval = setInterval(cycleBackgrounds, 5000);
    // register onClick handler for the button with id "myButton"
    $('#myButton').on('click', function(){
      if (window.slideshow_interval != -1){
          clearInterval(window.slideshow_interval);
          window.slideshow_interval = -1;
      }
      cycleBackgrounds();        
    });
});
```